# how do i achieve this in TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

see below figure, it has- TableView & tablecell have same background image i.e.tableview & tablecell must not look different. in tableCell there must be one button .
[image]

Comment: What did u do to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did this following way:
I created two prototype cells having different Cell identifier
e.g. left cell identifier= Cell1 & right cell identifier=Cell2.

simply put one round-rect button, make it as custom because it shows only in image shape
made table cell background color as clearColor, it requires because for the feel of table cell & tableview must look same.

also set tableView background color as clearColor & add images to both button.

```
if ((indexPath.row)%2!=0)
    {
        CellIdentifier=@"Cell1";
    }
    else
    {
        CellIdentifier=@"Cell2";

    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIButton *topicButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    NSString *topicNameLabel=[_topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you'll have to create a customized UITableViewCell.

1. You'll required 4 background image for your cell.

   a. Image Facing right.    b. Rollover image facing right.    c.
       Image Facing left.    d. Rollover image facing left.

You'll have to set alternate image to your cell. And when you click on the cell you'll need to change the background image of that particular cell to Rollover image.
Also you'll have to manage the frames of your rest of the control accordingly.

Comment: I agree with @Rushi. Creating a custom UITableViewCell is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but the image. You have to set an image in every tableviewcell by passing the condition

```
if(indexpath.row/2 == 0)
    <set_image1>
else
   <set_image2>
```

then adjust other parameters according to your desired frame position.

Note: You need to use dynamic tableviewcell height &
      You need for images for this.Two when cell is not selected & rest two when cell got selected

Enjoy Programming!